# .htaccess & Mod_Rewrite

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, .htaccess

I'm creating a website. I have this code in the .htaccess file:
 `RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^/([0-9][0-9])/$ /redirect.php?id=$1`

But when I go to, for example **/ASEi** it says **404 Not Found**
What's the problem?

Answer (score 2):

```
RewriteRule ^([0-9][0-9])$ /redirect.php?id=$1
```

Should probably work. Though what you're doing here, is to rewrite addresses from http://www.example.com/12 (two-digit numeric ID only) to http://www.example.com/redirect.php?id=12

Based on your example (*/ASEI*) I'm not sure if that's what you really want.